# Automate testing for jQuery 2.x compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, node.js, jquery-2.0

I have a very large code base of JavaScript code that currently all runs on jQuery 1.8. I plan on moving to jQuery 2.1 very soon and know that I have a lot of code that will break.

Does anyone know of a decent way to parse through my code and automatically tell me what files/lines in my code will definitely break? This way I can easily comb through the code and update what needs to be.

I hoped to find a ruby gem or node module that would do this for me but never did find one. Do you know of anything that I could leverage?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/. It should be able to detect deprecated features.